# Push a detail view in UITableViewCell class

Tags: ios, uiview

My class inherit from `UITableViewCell`, i have make some custom transitions to push a new detail view when an image get selected.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.masterView duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                    animations:^ { 
                        [self.masterView addSubview:self.detailImage];
                    }
                    completion:nil];
```

My code works fine, the `detailImage` subview is shown with a transition, but this transition is not what i want exactly. What i want to perform is a simple transition from bottom to up. The list of `UIViewAnimation` doesn't contain such animation.

Is there any way to use that transition without changing my class inheritance to `UINavigationController` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, the code below may be what you want.

```
CGRect detailImageFrameOri = self.detailImage.frame; 
CGRect detailImageFrame = detailImageFrameOri;
detailImageFrame.origin.y += self.detailImage.frame.size.height;
self.detailImage.frame = detailImageFrame;

[self.masterView addSubview:self.detailImage];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.detailImage.frame = detailImageFrameOri;
}];
```

Hope this can help you.

Edit:
from top to bottom,

```
CGRect detailImageFrame = self.detailImage.frame;
detailImageFrame.origin.y += self.detailImage.frame.size.height;

[self.masterView addSubview:self.detailImage];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                 animations:^{
                     self.detailImage.frame = detailImageFrame;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [self.detailImage removeFromSuperview];      
                 }];
```

Comment: Could you please provide the manner to pop(dismiss) that detail view vertically (from top to bottom)?

Comment: @luca you can change the origin.y, the method are same. Like this detailImageFrame.origin.y -= self.detailImage.frame.size.height;

Comment: I had the same idea `detailImageFrame.origin.y -= self.detailImage.frame.size.height;`, but, that make it a bit weird, instead of disappearing, it re-shows up again with a transition from top to bottom.